# how to update element in array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

i need update element in array of array

```
data ={ dataId :'dataId', field1:'fieldEnum',
        items[{itemCategory:'itemEnum', 
              itemData:[{_id:'idItem',value:'itemValue'}]}
             ]
     }
```

> how i can patch **itemValue** to **newValue** ?

, i try this code with feathers and mongoose, but not working :(

```
app.service('serviceName').patch(dataId,{
      'data.items.$':{
        'itemData.$.value':newValue
      }
    },{query:
        {'data.field1':"fieldEnum",'data.items.itemData._id':idItem}});
  }
```

Mongoose remplace 'data.items.$' with good value data.itemsindexOfElementInArray .. but seconde 'itemData.$.value' no remplace $ by index

Comment: Use `.update` instead of `.patch`. See https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose/issues/165

Comment: thx for answer, but when i try update,
I have to update all the properties of data object. but  I want update only itemValue :(